# Why doesn't my text show up with style when using SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have a problem with a `SpannableString` object.

Below's a short example:

```
SpannableString spanstr = new SpannableString("Bold please!");
spanstr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanstr.length(), 0);

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append(spanstr);
sb.append("\n"); // A newline
sb.append("The first line is bold. This one isn't.");

CharSequence cq = sb.subSequence(0, sb.length());
// ^There's no such method to return a SpannableString,
// so I try to return a CharSequence instead.

// And then, at last:
TextView contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_id);
contentView.setText(cq);
```

What the example's trying to do is showing this:

> **Bold please!**
>   The first line is bold. This one isn't.

But the problem is: the first line of the text won't show up in bold.

Why doesn't it do it expected?

Comment: contentView.setText(sb);

Comment: I have same issue. Did you din any solution. It's not a hard work. But I couln'f make any simple solution yet. All of the above answers is not working too

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the spannable string builder for setting as text in textview :

```
contentView.setText(sb);
```

or else you can do like this :

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanstr = new SpannableStringBuilder("Bold please!");
spanstr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanstr.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanstr.append("\n");
spanstr.append("The first line is bold. This one isn't.");
contentView.setText(spanstr);
```

Answer (score 2):

use SpannableStringBuilder instance itself.

```
contentView.setText(sb);
```

output with your code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I called `toString()` on `spannableBuilder` and couldn't understand why I was not seeing a styled text.

Comment: @RenatKaitmazov You should not call toString() method on SpannableBuilder, if you do so it will consider it as String, not a styled text

Answer (score 2):

Try the below. You need to set the spannable string to the textview. So set the spannable string to your text as below

```
String s= "The first line is bold. This one isn't";
String title="Bold Please!";  
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_id);
tv.setText("");
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(title);
ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, ss1.length(), 0);
tv.append(ss1);
tv.append("\n");
tv.append(s);
```

I tried the above and you can see the resulting snapshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. It's working like charm as what I want to implement

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom font in your device. There is such a silly bug i think. Please change your custom font to default in your device and try again.

Answer (score 0):

late for the answer but for future reader who facing this problem,

make sure you **don't** call `toString()` when setting builder into textview

```
val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
builder.setspan(xxxxxxx)
```

do this :

```
textview.text = builder
```

and dont do this :

```
textview.text = builder.toString() //will remove the styling
```

alas, the styling from SpanableStringBuilder wont work