# Applying style to selected text of a String in android?

Tags: java, android, string, styles, conditional-statements

I have a small doubt and I would like if you could make. 
Currently, I have a String and I check if a word using ".contains("String");" as for example:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtr);

for (int x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
    tv.append("Text one\n");
    tv.append("Text Two\n");
}

if(tv.getText().toString().contains("Text one")){
    //Found
}else{
    //Not found
}
```

My question is this. Can I do conditional and if you find the word I'm looking, apply a style?

```
if(tv.getText().toString().contains("Text one")){
    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); //I found text. Apply text bold
}else{
    //Not found
}
```

Regards!

Comment: You want to set bold to only `Text one`?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, according to the condition

Comment: The changes you make to the TextView (bold, color) will affect all Strings in that TextView. Sounds what your looking for is a SpannableString which can set spans (such as bold, color or typeface) to certain parts of the String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `SpannableString`.

In the below all characters of # is set to Red. You can make it bold

[Create clickable link in text view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908547/create-clickable-link-in-text-view-in-android)

Edit: Just found the example for making it bold

[Why doesn't my text show up with style when using SpannableStringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060991/why-doesnt-my-text-show-up-with-style-when-using-spannablestringbuilder)