# SpannableString is not working in a Dialog

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I want to show the `spanString` in Bold style and rest of the string in normal style in `TextView`. But the whole `TextView` showed in normal style only.   Please help me.

```
if ((mStoreListValue.get(pos).getStoreStatus().equals("CLOSED"))){

   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getRootView().getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.resclosed_dialog);
   ImageView btn_close =  dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
   TextView txt_close =  dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_closed);

   SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(sname);
   spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   txt_close.setText(spanString +  " " + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.closed));

   btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
              dialog.dismiss();
         }
    });
  dialog.show();
```

Comment: `spanString +  " " + ...` – This is implicitly calling `toString()` on `spanString`, which strips any span info on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my text show up with style when using SpannableStringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060991/why-doesnt-my-text-show-up-with-style-when-using-spannablestringbuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(sname);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
builder.append(spanString);
builder.append(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.closed));
txt_close.setText(builder);
```

Instead of this

```
txt_close.setText(spanString +  " " + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.closed));
```

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim happy to help you my friend

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you just concat `SpannableString` with `String` which will be result as `toString()`(a Normal String with hash code of object). Use a single `String` with multiple `Span`.

See the following example.

```
    String s1="My app";
    String s2= "Close";
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(s1+s2);
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, s1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), s1.length(), (s1+s2).length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spanString);
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the one indicated as the correct one, since it also gives a reason why the initial code of the questioner does not work as it should

Answer (score 0):

Using String templating, you can have a string resource: 
`&lt;b>` indicates  bold, 
`%1$d` indicates I am expecting a digit/number
so I get (**5 min** away) in the textview

```
//xml
<string name="confirm_eta_text"> &lt;b>%1$d min &lt;/b> away</string>

// Java   
mEta.setText(
Compat.fromHtml(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.confirm_eta_text), 5)));
```

[Android String Formatting](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)